# error in path using JUST BOIL ME plug in for TINYMCE -- php

Tags: php, jquery

Hope you can help me solve my issue. I am using **JUSTBOILME** as an image uploader for **TINYMCE** text editor. I am incorporating it to PHP. My question is I am having an error when i am trying to upload an image to the text editor of tinymce using the just boil me plug in. I am having the error... "**The upload path does not appear to be valid**." I have set the is_allowed to true. I am using LOCALHOST. Are there any issues on using localhost for this? Thanking you in advanced..

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on whether you have your site in a subfoler or not. If you look further down the config.php page you will see a `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` assignment. I echoed this on my index page which lead me to the fact that I needed to included my subfoler in the line `$config['img_path'] = '/subFolderName/images/uploads';` Make sure that you have no trailing slash